# Upsizing a Gas Line

Tags: pipe, natural-gas

I currently have a natural gas pipe coming into my house with a 1" diameter. It currently terminates after about 20' and supplies a hot water heater (33,000 BTU) and a furnace (60,000 BTU).

I want to extend the run 50' to another corner of the house where it will hopefully supply a dryer, BBQ and stove.

I've been doing the sizing calculations for continuing a 1" line and it's going to be a tight fit in terms of capacity.

Since line capacity is a function of distance and pipe diameter, will I get more capacity if I increase the pipe size at the 20' mark to 1 1/4"?

Comment: Have you asked your gas company this question?  They often provide help or even do these things for free/discount because they love people using more gas.